# How can I put table data to a vector/list?

Tags: r

I need to import information from txt files. I used:

```
 in1 <- read.table("store1_in.txt", head = True)
 in2 <- read.table("store2_in.txt", head = True) 
...
```

but it is not compact, so i was adviced to use cicles and vectors:

```
for (i in c(1:10)){
    input[i] <- read.table(file = paste0('store',i,'_in.txt'), head = TRUE)
  }
```

but I received the warning message:

> In input[i] <- read.table(file = paste0("store", i, "_in.txt"),  :
>   `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

What I did do wrong?

Comment: `input <- lapply(list.files(pattern = 'store\\d+_in.txt'), read.table, header = TRUE)`.

Comment: Or create `input <- list('vector', 10)` first and inside the loop use `input[[i]]` with two `[[`. See [Difference between `[` and `[[`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code snippet it is not clear what `input` is. If it is a list, just use the double square brackets:

```
input <- list()

for (i in 1:10) {
  input[[i]] <- read.table(file = paste0('foo',i,'.txt'), header = TRUE)
}
```

However, I would use `lapply` instead:

```
input <- lapply(1:10, function(i) read.table(file = paste0('foo',i,'.txt'), header = TRUE))
```